# Selecting only the first specifically-typed child of an element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to select the first child of `<body>` that is a `<div>`, and *only* that element.

I'm having trouble formulating the right selector for the element I want. I could simply give it an ID, but now I'm curious about whether this is possible in general.

In a simple situation like this:

```
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

I can just use the child selector:

```
body > div {
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
}
```

But what happens now if there are two `<div>` elements underneath `<body>`?

```
<body>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

Well, now I can just use the `first-child` pseudo-class to make my selection. This works great:

```
body > div:first-child {
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
}
```

But wait just a second. What if someone goes and sticks another child element into `<body>` before my `<div>`?

```
<body>
  <a name="top"></a>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

How can I select only the first `<div>` child in this case (in general)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the [first-of-type](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3afirst-of-type) selector

```
body > div:first-of-type
{
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
}
```

**[Edit]** Check out [nth-of-type](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3anth-of-type) while you're at it.

**[Edit]** Added a child selector.

Comment: also, i think i'll need to use `body>div:first-of-type`, otherwise first-of-type subdivs will get matched

Answer (score 2):

`:first-child` will only select something if it is the first child of its parent

`:first-of-type` will work however support for this is fairly recent and won't work on older browsers (read IE): http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-firstoftype

Depending on what you want to support, or how complex your code is, you may have to fall back to giving your div a class.

Comment: There is no ":first" selector in CSS (although, as you point out, there IS one in jQuery).

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me [first-of-type](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-of-type-pseudo) does the job.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a probability that "someone goes and sticks another child" then you have no other options other than giving it an ID.

For example if you have a `<div>` and someone will insert another `<div>` before yours then no existing CSS selectors would work for you.

Comment: but wouldn't the addition of another `<div>` child be the only thing that would throw a wrench in the `first-of-type` pseudoclass?

Comment: If someone will add another div then :first-of-type selector will match theirs element but not yours. Or I do not understand your question.

Comment: that's what i'm saying: any element other than `<div>` would have no effect. you're right.